# How to remove and iterate over the same List without getting ConcurrentModificationException or IllegalStateException Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to delete data from a History table and also want to remove the data from the historyList .

If I use the below code i get ConcurrentModificationException .

If I use iterator inside foreach I get IllegalStateException .

I have a History class as an Entity with hid as **@Id** and **@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)**

if i remove the h**istoryList.remove(d)** from code i get **org.hibernate.StaleStateException:**

Is there any way to overcome this problem . Please help if possible.

Thanks

```
 for (History d : historyList) {

        Transaction txn = session.beginTransaction();
        session.delete(d);
        historyList.remove(d);
        System.out.println("Deleted Successfully");
        txn.commit();

    }
```

Comment: What's `historyList`? Does it belong to another entity?

Answer (score -1):

If you're using an iterator, don't use a for loop

```
Iterator it = historyList.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) { 
History h = it.next() ;
Transaction txn = session.beginTransaction(); session.delete(h);
it.remove();
System.out.println("Deleted Successfully"); txn.commit(); }
```